# How can I hide the ID of application in the android google play store URL?

Tags: android, google-play

i am not sure if this is the right place to ask this but here goes:

i have an app for a client with my company's name in the package name. it was first uploaded to my company's google play account but then the client requested it should be transferred to their account later on. after doing that they noticed that it shows our company's name in the URL on google play on the browser and they requested it should be renamed. so my question is:

- can the id be removed from the url? for example this  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?**id=com.facebook.katana** becomes https://play.google.com/store/apps/details/**facebook**
- can I change the name of the package and replace the already existing app? (I guess not since the package name is the id of the application...)

thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Upload a new version with your client's company name as part of package name.After   it is published and unpublished the app which includes your company name.

Comment: this way the users with the application will not get an update for the new application

Comment: Maybe use the short url (i.e https://goo.gl/ ) to hide the google play origin url

Comment: well actually that won't help since still if you searched here:https://play.google.com/store you will still get the full url

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea to rename it. My suggestion is if your app uploaded recently and also it's a free app,and maybe there are a few users to use it.You should uploaded new one as soon as possible in order to let new users to download the newer one .Update the old one to add a link at main page of old app to recommend user to use new one. After 1-2 days unpublished the old one.

Comment: thank you Frankie for your suggestion but the application already has more than 1,000 downloads :)